# SQL to LOOP through columns and set values to each column per iteration

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to query sum activity for each user (variable number of users) for each day in a month(30days).

Due to the nature of the query its faster and less complicated to get the activity per day basis. I have made a table with 30 columns named "Day1","Day2".."Day30".

My plan is to loop it 30times where 'i'th iteration updates values in 'i'th column.

Is PIVOT applicable in this scenario. Or is it possible to loop as "Day"+i when handling columns? How do I go on about it.

EDIT: Mostly a question on process and syntax not of design. Is it possible to use column name strings to select them across loops

Comment: Seems like a poor table design with 30 day columns. You should have one row per day instead, and then simply GROUP BY.

Comment: Nobody worked january the 31 ?

Comment: Number of columns have been decided at 30 not 31.

Comment: As @jarlh stated, this was poorly designed. Was it another great idea from a non technical manager?

Comment: Read about `Date dimension` tables. They are especially good for pivoting data. For you question: it's easy to generate SQL for predefined set of fields. But I hope you will go for `dimensional modelling`. Look for [Datawarehose Toolkit](https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques) by R.Kimball, M.Ross

Comment: Yes, `pivot` can be used for rearranging the data, assuming you know how to calculate the column for each row in the original data.